# realistic jump like all games in cocos2d iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

i am new on game development so can any one guide me or help to make the jump in the game more realistic like monster inc run,mega run have in which user can jump or also make the long jump if it pressed long on screen. i tried the box2d code for making simple jump i am using this code

```
b2Vec2 impulse = b2Vec2([self body]->GetMass()*vert, [self body]->GetMass()*horz);
    b2Vec2 impulsePoint = [self body]->GetWorldCenter();//GetWorldPoint(b2Vec2(5.0/100.0, -15.0/100.0));
    [self body]->ApplyLinearImpulse(impulse, impulsePoint);
```

but it's not giving me the correct result i want the exact logic or technique which all the games have. Can any one suggest me the book,tutorial,or sample code so i can make my game more attractive with game play and also tell me how i can make the longer jump thing. i searched a lot but i didn't find any good tutorial or thing on the web so i decided to asked it here and sorry for my english i am not good with it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know Cocos2D, but I can suggest you how I've seen it done:
When the user starts pressing the button, you start applying a vertical force to the character, this force continues applying for a certain ammount of time (having the character achieve more height) or until the user stops pressing the button.
That way if its just a tap then the force applied is little, but if the button is pressed for longer the character jumps higher

Comment: i did that thing too but it's not making it realistic like i am doing if user press i make a little larger vertical velocity on the player by using applylinearimpluse and also i make a variable true for press state to check that if user is remain touched and on that variable  i giving him small amount of applylinearimpluse but by this i am not getting perfect result about jump some time it go to much high on just press or some time it just jump little it working too fast

Comment: Well then you're obviously not checking things correctly, you don't need any variable for checking if the user is pressing the button or not, just evaluate it every frame and perform the correct action acordingly

Comment: i made the check b/c if i simply apply small amount of impulse on it like you said till at specific height then it will not jump if i jump tap it that's why i am giving it little high impulse on tap and then checking if the user continues pressing state then give it more impulse till specific height or impulse rate